# Camera zoom Google Glass XE16

Tags: android, android-camera, google-glass, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm working on an application for Google Glass which relies on scanning various QR codes during the setup phase. Prior to the XE16 version, the custom autozoom function I'd created worked flawlessly. The camera would zoom in as long as the user's head movement stayed within set margins and reset zoom if these margins were exceeded.

The Glass we use for development has been updated to XE16 (Android 4.4.2) and the zoom function no longer works.

```java
if (mCamera != null) {
  Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
  parameters.setZoom(currentZoom); // zoom already incremented

  Log.i("ZoomManager", String.format("Set zoom to %d/%d", currentZoom, maximumZoom));

  mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

  Log.i("ZoomManager", String.format("Current zoom %d/%d", mCamera.getParameters().getZoom(), maximumZoom));
}
```

Running this code outputs the following.

> 04-17 13:22:24.300: I/ZoomManager(11398): Set zoom to 3/60
>   04-17 13:22:24.347: I/ZoomManager(11398): Current zoom 0/60
>   04-17 13:22:24.644: I/ZoomManager(11398): Set zoom to 6/60
>   04-17 13:22:24.699: I/ZoomManager(11398): Current zoom 0/60
>   04-17 13:22:25.011: I/ZoomManager(11398): Set zoom to 9/60
>   04-17 13:22:25.050: I/ZoomManager(11398): Current zoom 0/60
>   04-17 13:22:25.332: I/ZoomManager(11398): Set zoom to 12/60
>   04-17 13:22:25.371: I/ZoomManager(11398): Current zoom 0/60
>   04-17 13:22:25.667: I/ZoomManager(11398): Set zoom to 15/60
>   04-17 13:22:25.714: I/ZoomManager(11398): Current zoom 0/60
>   .... All the way to 60 as zoom level is stored locally

I couldn't find any related changes to the camera but maybe I overlooked something. Has anyone else experienced this problem, or does anyone have any insights as to how I can fix this?

Comment: In the end, this was fixed through an update to the XE version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Google engineer has created a bug  ，in   XE16.2 is  ok!